# Is there a way to suppress "___.tex changed; really edit the buffer?" at org-export to latex?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs 25.3.2 with org-mode version 9.1.13.
Whenever I use export an org-mode file to latex multiple times, I am prompted:

> __.tex changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)

Is there a way to suppress this prompt, only at the time of org-export?